# ! Package keyval Error: language={bash},numbers=left undefined

Tags: listings, optional-arguments

The following M(n)WE gives me the message:

```
! Package keyval Error: language={bash},numbers=left undefined.
```

Seems like the Key-Values are not being defined in my variable properly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{temp.tex}
for i in {1..3}; do
 echo $i
done
\end{filecontents}

\def\opts{[language={bash},numbers=left]}
\def\fn{temp.tex}
\lstinputlisting[language={bash},numbers=left]{\fn}%this line works fine
\lstinputlisting[\opts]{\fn}%this line does not work???
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a new style with `\lstdefinestyle`, and use `style=<stylename>`, instead of a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{opts}{
   language={bash},
   numbers=left
}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{temp.tex}
for i in {1..3}; do
 echo $i
done
\end{filecontents}

\def\fn{temp.tex}
\lstinputlisting[language={bash},numbers=left]{\fn}%this line works fine
\lstinputlisting[style=opts]{\fn}%this line works fine
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the only "thing" that you passed to `\lstinputlisting` was `\writelstopts` which, in the example, was a single token that contained `language={bash},numbers=left`, which is not a valid option.

What you want is to pass the *contents* of `\writelstopts`, so you have to expand them before `\lstinputlisting` tries to do its thing. A pair of `\expandafter`s solve this issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{writelst}[2][]{%
\def\writelstopts{#1}%
\def\writelstfn{#2}%
%call-another-command-here{#2}
\lstinputlisting[#1]{\writelstfn}%this line works fine
}
{
%call-yet-another-command-here
\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[\writelstopts]{\writelstfn}%this line does not work???
}

\begin{document}
\begin{writelst}[language={bash},numbers=left]{test.sh}
some bash code here
\end{writelst}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW! thank you very much, that is just what I need.